# How to determine if the right mouse button is down or not in a MOUSE_MOVE event?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

For the `MOUSE_MOVE` event, the [documentation says](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/MouseEvent.html#MOUSE_MOVE) there is a `buttonDown` property to indicate whether or not the left mouse button is currently down. But how can I determine if the right button is down?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not, but you can do this by setting a flag inbetween Right Mouse down and Right mouse up. If you listen on capture with a high priority, it will be available in all other mouse events.

In your document class or main timeline frame 1, add the following code:

```
var isRightMouseDown:Boolean = false;

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.RIGHT_MOUSE_DOWN, globalMouseDown,true,int.MAX_VALUE)
function globalMouseDown(e:MouseEvent):void {
    isRightMouseDown = true;
}

stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.RIGHT_MOUSE_UP,globalMouseUp,true,int.MAX_VALUE)
function globalMouseUp(e:MouseEvent):void {
    isRightMouseUp = false;
}
```

Now you have a var you can access in your mouse move listeners.  If using timeline code, access it outside the main timeline by doing `MovieClip(root).isRightMouseDown`.  If using a document class, define it as static `public static var isRightMouseDown:Boolean` and access it like so from anywhere in your app:  `MyMainClassName.isRightMouseDown`. (replace MyMainClassName with whatever you've called your document class)

When you add the listeners above, putting the third parameter as `true` and the fourth parameter as `int.MAX_VALUE` will ensure this listener will be processed before any others listening for the same event in your application.

For more information about how events work and their phases, see this:
http://www.adobe.com/devnet/actionscript/articles/event_handling_as3.html

Comment: How about you hold the right button out of the Flash window and move the mouse into the Flash window?

Comment: Nothing you can do in that case (initial right mouse down happens outside of flash having the focus) - at least as far as I know.